# Как работает annotate?

Tags: django

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)


class User(AbstractUser):
    selected_tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True, related_name='users')
```

Нужно получить список тегов так, чтобы знать, с какими связан определенный пользователь.

```
queryset = Tag.objects.annotate(selected=Subquery(user.selected_tags.filter(pk=OuterRef('pk')).values('pk')))
```

У меня получается так, но в queryset[0].selected находится/ненаходится id тега, что странно, и думаю затратно, мне только нужно там true/false (выбран этот тег или нет). 
Как правильно составить запрос?
Буду раз ссылке на документацию на русском языке по этой теме

Comment: Не уверен, но может так `queryset[0].selected[0].id`?

Comment: А что значит выбран? Вы хотите получить все теги, с которыми связан пользователь или которые выбрал?

Comment: Может, нужно что-то такое: `Tag.objects.annotate(selected=F('users'))`?

Comment: @Александр Есть определенный user, он выбрал несколько тегов(selected_tags). Вот теперь я хочу получить список всех тегов, и при этом сразу знать, какие выбрал именно этот user. На псевдокоде это должно выглядить так: Tag.objects.annotate(selected=(users.filter(pk=user.pk).exists())

Answer (score 0):

> Нужно получить список тегов так, чтобы знать, с какими связан определенный пользователь.

```
Tag.objects.filter(userset=user) 
# user_set или user, точно не помню, 
# так как обычно указываю related_name для FK и M2M полей
```

Annotate здесь не нужен

Comment: А теперь мне нужно пройтись по всему списку тегов, и знать, когда очередной  тег входит в это (Tag.objects.filter(userset=user)) множество. мне как делать if tag in Tag.objects.filter(userset=user) ?

Comment: @Антон, вы задали вопрос, вы получили ответ, примите решение и задайте новый вопрос, а не требовать, что вам теперь нужно не выбрав решение.

Comment: @And Я не требую отвечать на на новый вопрос, я пытаюсь ему донести суть текущего, ибо этот ответ не решает проблемы, которую я описал

Comment: Мне нужны все теги, а так я получаю только часть

Comment: @Антон, да вы вопрос свой прочитайте, мало того, что там каша, ну и о том что вам нужно получить все теги, об этом ничего не сказано.